# How to setup Letsencrypt for Google Cloud load balancer?

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine, certbot

I've setup my Google Cloud Project to use a load balancer in combination with auto scaling instance templates. Currently the instance group only has one instance.

My domain name successfully refers to the load balancers IP. Till these steps everything is working correctly.

Now I want to setup SSL for this project. I would like to do this with the Letsencrypt service, however I'm having no success when trying to set this up.

In the Google Cloud Engine load balancer window there is an option to setup an earlier created certificate with Google Cloud shell to the load balancer frontend. Unfortunately I can only create a .csr and .key file with the Google Cloud Shell. Furthermore, I can create an unsafe ssl certificate and get the .cert file from it, but I would like to create a safe SSL cert file using letsencrypt. The Letsencrypt services requires direct access to the domain from to command line interface the commando was executed on, this is probably the reason why I’m getting an error indicating the domain name cannot be retrieved.

I’m looking for a way to install the Letsencrypt certificate on the loadbalancer using Google Cloud. Is there a way how I can manually create a .cert file with letsencrypt instead of installing this directly? If not is there another way or service to create a .cert file from a .csr and .key file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is this docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/bloomapi/letsencrypt-gcloud-balancer. You just need to create any virtual machine and give it full access to the API. After that, install docker on it and run the docker container. The certificates on the load balancer will automatically renew every month!

Answer (score 0):

Since GCP allow to use [self-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs), you should be able to use SSL certificate or generate one in order to protect your site ans make it secure for visitors. Is the same use as letsencrypt, because is free and it easier to use a Google Managed SSL certificate.

Review the following guidance and let me know your comments. Happy new year.

Comment: Hello! I have already read this guide. My question is how can I automatically renew certificates?

Comment: If your certificates are managed, yes they can be renewed automatically. If they are not, the answer is no. Please review the following information about it https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#renewal